# EMU8086 adds value to wrong register

Tags: nasm, emu8086

```
var1 db 1h, 2h
var2 db 2h
MOV AL, [var1 + 1]
MOV [var2], AL
```

If I emulate this code, I see EMU8086 set up AH (not AL) part of register AX. Why?

Answer (score 0):

EMU8086 begins to process at the beginning (`var1`) and interpretes the bytes as instruction and following bytes accordingly. So, the code looks for EMU8086 like

```
ADD [BP+SI], AX
ADD AH, [BX + SI] + 00001
MOV [00002], AL
```

As you can see, this code changes `AH` but not `AL`. In short: EMU8086 requires a proper DOS program.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first load var1 address into si after do this operation

```
lea si,var1
mov al,[si+1]
mov [si+2],al
```